# Is there a way to swap out a Nokogiri XML node with another one?

Tags: xml, nokogiri

For example, if I have the Nokogiri::XML::Nodeset below, how can I swap out the second node (the entire second dict) for the node to swap in? Is there a way to do it without going through each field and replacing them (because in the actual XML, each dict has hundreds of fields)?

```
<array>
<dict>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>Test</string>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>Phone</key>
  <string>123-456-7890</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

The Nokogiri::XML::Element that I want to swap in:

```
<dict>
  <key>Email</key>
  <string>skafjdksf@sdjlf.com</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself, in case anyone in the future needs this information.

To swap the node out with the replacement one:

```
nodeToSwapOut.previous.next.replace(newNode)
```

And then write the new XML to a new file:

```
File.new(newFile, 'w')
   File.open(newFile, 'w') do |f|
   f.write(oldFile.to_xml)
end
```